# How can we have app based authentication for a community wifi?

Tags: wireless-networking, authentication, 802.1x

We are building a community wi-fi network and using a captive portal for authentication ,since it uses http it is not secure. To overcome that we  are trying to build an application which securely transmits the data over the wireless link and authenticates the client to join the network.

Can anyone suggest guideline and steps to follow while building that application.

Comment: Heya - this is not a good question for Superuser. We try to focus more on definitive questions and answers here, and this kind of question will generate lots of discussions since it's so broad.

Comment: usually, we will Secure WiFi Authentication with RADIUS https://jumpcloud.com/blog/what-is-wifi-authentication